# Postman: test throws assertion error `expected null to deeply equal undefined`

Tags: javascript, postman, chai

I have an API response as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "instance_id": 1400,
        "entity_uuid": 21,
        "field": null,
        "old_value": null,
        "new_value": null,
        "kind": "C",
        "updated_by": "binish",
        "updated_dt": "2017-12-28T13:19:22.000Z"
    }
]
```

I want to validate the value of `old_value` field in Postman and below is the code:

```
var data = pm.response.json(responseBody);
var oldValue = data.old_value;
var nullValue = null;

pm.test("Old Value is NULL", function(){
    pm.expect(nullValue).to.be.eql(oldValue);
});
```

The test throws an error:

> "AssertionError: expected null to deeply equal undefined".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The response is an array: `data[0].old_value`

Comment: I did try that and it gives me the same error. In fact, for the same response, console.log(oldValue) displayed 'null' in the POSTman console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use something like this to check that the `old_value`property is `null`? This is using the built-in module [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10) to allow you to loop through the data in a cleaner way than a native JS `for` loop would do.

```
pm.test("Old Value is NULL", () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json(), (arrItem) => {
        console.log(arrItem)
        pm.expect(arrItem.old_value).to.be.null
    })
})
```

[image: Postman]

Using the data that you attached to the question, I extended this to add another object into the array. This was to show you that this test will check `each` object `old_value` property for the same `null` value, rather than limiting you to just looking at the first `[0]` object.

[image: Postman]

Comment: How can I check for not null value? I saw that `.not.eql` or `.not.equal` are not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are mistake in this line: `var data = pm.response.json(responseBody);`
you don't need that argument, because, as you can see in [documentation](http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Response.html), argument's are optional here, and first argument is a `function()`,
in my opinion, it will work: after removing this argument:

```
var data = pm.response.json();
var oldValue = data[0].old_value; //data is array
var nullValue = null;

pm.test("Old Value is NULL", function(){
    pm.expect(nullValue).to.be.eql(oldValue);
});
```